# URL rewriting with nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I've recently set up a virtual host using nginx.  The website being hosted needs to redirect URL's containing `'/old/'` - to the same url without `'/old/'`.  For example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/old/a/b/c to www.mywebsite.com/a/b/c
www.mywebsite.com/old/a to www.mywebsite.com/a
www.mywebsite.com/old/a/b/c/d/e to www.mywebsite.com/a/b/c/d/e
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help:

rewrite ^/old/(.+)$ http://myebsite.com/$1 permanent;

If not try to combine it whit if (!-f $request_filename) { here }

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
server {
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    location /old/ {
        rewrite ^/old/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        # bla bla bla and other usual stuff
    }
}
```